# Binding to correct model - with same name

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that displays 2 forms (the array has 2 items)

I have an empty input for each of these, that has the same model, something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat=“group in groups”>
    <form>
        <input type=“text” ng-model=“group.name” placeholder=“name” />
    </form>
</div>
```

Now this works well, until I try to enter text into the first input, it automatically enters into the second as well.

Is there an easy way to bind to the input i’m actually typing in?

Thanks

Comment: A better question would be why are you using the same model on two identical inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [PLNKR example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsHyj48UnS2dnWPQwQd2?p=preview) doesn't match your question.

### Simplifying your code:

```
<!-- Top loop doesn't repeat -->
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <div ng-repeat="g in group">
        <div ng-repeat="info in g.info.data">
             <input ng-model="info.name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>

                   <!-- This is the problem -->
        <input ng-model="test.name" placeholder="Name">
        <button ng-click="nameAdd($parent.$index)">
            Add
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The input with the <kbd>Add</kbd> button uses the same `ng-model` name. Also here are three nested loops when only two are needed.

### The Data

```
$scope.groups = {
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Group 1",
        "site_id": 3,
        "info": {
            "data": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Jim"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Group 2",
        "site_id": 3,
        "info": {
            "data": [{
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Bob"
            }, {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Terry"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

### Change the template to:

```
<!-- remove top loop 
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
-->
    <div ng-repeat="groupDatum in groups.data" ng-cloak>
        <div ng-repeat="infoDatum in groupDatum.info.data">
             <input ng-model="infoDatum.name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>

                   <!-- use groupDatum to store new name -->
        <input ng-model="groupDatum.newName" placeholder="Name">
                   <!-- use groupDatum as arg to ng-click -->
        <button ng-click="nameAdd(groupDatum)">
            Add
        </button>
    </div>
```

### The `nameAdd` function:

```
$scope.nameAdd = function(groupDatum) {
    var newId = uniqueId();
    var newName = groupDatum.newName;
    groupDatum.info.data.push({id: newId, name: newName});
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you so much! I have implemented the changes and can confirm that it now works as expected

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
<div ng-repeat=“group in groups”>
<form>
    <input type=“text” ng-model=“groups[$index].name” placeholder=“name” />
</form>
</div>
```

you also probably put the form tag outside of the repeater unless you want to create a new from for every input tag

Comment: How would i then access this in my controller?

Comment: $scope.groups?  you already have that variable.  the one you are using for ng-repeat

Comment: also if you name your form, angularjs will create an object for every form, but not sure if that's needed.

Comment: group in groups does the groups[$index] for you. It sounds to me like the same object is just in the array twice for whatever reason.

Comment: Well `groups` is a json array taken from a service call, so I'm just iterating over it to create 2 'groups' that contain the data from the json object. The input field is a simple input to add more data to the groups array.

Comment: can you post a plunkr or jsbin?  not sure what your goal is here.

Comment: The following is a small example: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsHyj48UnS2dnWPQwQd2?p=preview)